# mysql collation and indexes

Tags: php, mysql

What mysql collation should I use for my tables to support all european languages, all latin american languages, and maybe chinese, maybe asian languages? Thanks!

What is the rule when it comes to using indexes on mysql table columns? When should you not use an index for a column in a table?

Comment: indexes are there to speed up using the field in a where, group by, etc.. action. If you don't ever do antyhing but "select fieldname" with that field, then an index won't be of any use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `UTF8` would probably be the best choice, more specific; `utf8_general_ci`.
2. Indices should not be set in a table that you're going to perform a huge amount of insertions into. Indices speed up `SELECT`-queries, but these indices need to be rebuilt everytime you `INSERT` into the table. So, if you have a table that's... well, let's say it stores news articles - suitable indices might be the title or something that you might wanna "search" for.

Hope this clears some things up.

Answer (score 1):

utf8

utf8-general

is universal character set...

you should not use index when you're sure you will not search for it (via WHERE clause)